# Change remote IP address programmatically using WMI

Tags: c#, ip, wmi

I am writing an application to change the IP addresses of local and remote machines using WMI. This code successfully changes the gateway and DNS of the remote machine and the same code (in a different class and minus the management scope part) changes all of the data (the two IPs, gateway, DNS) locally. The problem is it doesn't change the remote IP address. Please can someone advise as I have looked everywhere for this answer?

I have tested on windows 7 and xp with no firewalls and with .net 4 installed on remote machines

```
class remoteIPChange
{
    public string setTillIP(string IPAddress1, string IPAddress2, string SubnetMask, string Gateway)
    {
        ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
        connection.Username = "username";
        connection.Password = "password";
        connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(
        "\\\\"+IPAddress1+"\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
        scope.Connect();

        ObjectGetOptions o = new ObjectGetOptions();

        ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");

        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass(scope,p,o);

        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if (!(bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
            continue;

            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject objNewIP = null;
                ManagementBaseObject objSetIP = null;
                ManagementBaseObject objNewGate = null;
                ManagementBaseObject objNewDNS = null;

                objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
                objNewDNS = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");

                //Set DefaultGateway
                objNewGate["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { Gateway };
                objNewGate["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

                //Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
                objNewIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { IPAddress1, IPAddress2 };
                objNewIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { SubnetMask, SubnetMask };

                //Set DNS servers
                objNewDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = new string[] {Gateway };

                //Invoke all changes
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, null);
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, null);
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objNewDNS, null);

                return ("Updated IPAddress to " + IPAddress + ", \nSubnetMask to " + SubnetMask + " \nand Default Gateway to " + Gateway + "!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ("Unable to Set IP : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return "code has not run";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the return value?  Do note the difficulty of staying connected to a remote machine when you change its IP address.  So don't be surprised to get return value 1, "Successful completion, reboot required".

Comment: It doesnt return an error code, it returns the "updated Ip address to...." message. I have managed to get this to work in the past but i cannot remember how

Comment: If you're changing the gateway, ensure you also have the route set up to that gateway - either on the target host and/or on the router(s). I'm guessing from your writeup that you're still able to communicate with the targets using the same old IP as before?

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the ReturnValue from the invokemethod on EnableStatic. I am pretty sure passing in a null for your subnet is your problem. Provide a valid array of subnets that match your ip addresses instead of that null.